# Rust diesel filter using start and end date with single column

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using diesel SQL for fetching the data from the Postgres table. Below is my table structure. I want to join the employee and accounts table and fetch data from the start date to end dates selected by the user. With single column `created_at` using the user_id.

```
#Emplyee table

| employee-id  | employee_name | empolyee_email|       
| -----------  | --------------|-------------  |
| 1            | ABC           |abc@mail.com   |
| 2            | xyz           |xyz@mail.com   |


# Account table

| account  | employee-id    | account-balnce | created_at|
| -------- | ----------     |--------------- |-----------|
| 1        | 1              |   2000         | 22/10/2021|
| 2        | 2              |   5000         | 01/09/2021|
```

Comment: Try calling the `inner_join` method of a table with either an `on` clause or a `joinable` macro. See also https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/prelude/trait.QueryDsl.html#method.inner_join and https://docs.diesel.rs/master/diesel/query_dsl/trait.JoinOnDsl.html for examples.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to use `between` with inner join for start and end date-time below is code.

```
let res= employee::table.inner_join(account::table.on(employee::dsl::employee_id.eq(account::dsl::employee_id)),)
            .filter(account::dsl::employee_id.eq(employeeId).and(account::created_at.between(start_date,end_date)))
            .load::<(Employee_Details,)>(&self.pool.get()?)?;
```

Comment: Found this from here: https://docs.rs/diesel/latest/diesel/expression_methods/trait.ExpressionMethods.html#method.between